# How do we apply conditional statements to an array in julia?

Tags: matlab, julia

In Matlab, we can use an if statement with an array to do some calculations.

Using the same array in Julia and applying the if statement brings an error. Anyone knows how to?

```matlab
   x = 1,2,3,4
   if x
      do something
   end
```

Comment: What does this if mean in Matlab, i. e. when does it trigger?

Comment: This isn't MATLAB syntax, so it's unclear what your expected output is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's `if x` statement makes sure that `x` is not empty and has entirely truth-y (nonzero/not false) values. Julia requires a single `Bool` value.

To duplicate Matlab's behavior in Julia, use `if !isempty(x) && all(!iszero, x)`.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed. @Matt B.